# error: import pychart , during install source code odoo 9.0

Tags: database, odoo

I wrote so many thing in requirements.txt and reinstalled but it didn't work out. I installed odoo 9.0 source code for windows. The command prompt is showing error:

> from pychart import *

What do I need to write in requirements.txt for pychart?

Comment: Is that al there is as error? That is hard to believe. And what is the commend/program that you run/started/executed when this error occurs?

Comment: whatever i write in command prompt this is for running odoo source code https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/setup/install.html

Comment: Sure, what is exactly the last  command you typed from that enormous guide in your command prompt and what was the complete stack trace that came with it? Please [edit] your question to add that instead of linking to that document because we need to understand which part you're at.

Answer (score 7):

As i just ran into the same problem unrelated to odoo.
The following command solved it for me:

```
pip install Python-Chart
```

Comment: Worked in CentOS, perfect

Answer (score 2):

To install the python packages for odoo you can use below command found from this [detailed odoo install guide](https://atularvind.com/install-odoo-10-in-ubuntu/)

```
cd /tmp && wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/odoo/odoo/9.0/requirements.txt && sudo pip install -r requirements.txt
```

It will install all the python dependacy in just one command.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but this link provide me real support https://odootricks.wordpress.com/2014/09/18/installing-odoo-8-on-centos-7-with-virtual-python-install/

Answer (score 1):

You have to install that package before you use that,                                    If are on ubuntu command is pip install pychart and if you are on windows the command is c:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe install pychart.I assume you have installed python on default folder c drive.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a module like `install_module` and on depends you can add required list of module to install. If you install that module it'll automatically install all depended module. I'm using this same. Instead of command prompt it'll be quite easy too. You can view the depends module list in `Technical Data` of that `install_modules`.

I Hope it'll be helpful.